# ASP.NET XML Web Service Return Wrong Data

Tags: asp.net, xml, iis, service, web

I have a XML Web Service hosted on IIS 6 and has been written by asp.net framework 4

Sometimes it returns wrong data and i should restart iis to resolved this problem

For example :

It should return something like this(Correct) :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <DataTable xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
- <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
- <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Food" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
- <xs:element name="Food">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="STATUS" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="CODE" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="TITLE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="FULL_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="TYPE" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="UNIT" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="PRICE" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="BREAKFAST" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="LUNCH" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="DINNER" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="MINIBAR" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="TERIA" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="DESSERT" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="MAIN_FOOD" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="DESSERT1" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="DRINK" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="MISC" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="PRE_FOOD" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="UNIT_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

but sometimes it returns this(Wrong answer) :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <DataTable xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
- <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
- <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Food" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
- <xs:element name="Food">
  <xs:complexType /> 
  </xs:element>
  </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" /> 
  </DataTable>
```

what should i do?

Comment: is the xml populated by something else, such as a database? If so, I'd look at the database connection as sometimes it's not supplying data

Comment: Yes, my web service connect to sql server 2008 r2 and get data from our database. But i'm sure that the problem isn't related to sql server, because Our windows application works correctly